# Decomission Active Directory DC role but keep DNS service

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I planed to move my AD's DC Server to a more controlled network environment. Now my 5 role has moved to the newly deployed DC Server, and next step will be decomission the old DC servers. Currently most of my servers's dns pointed to the old machine.

1. Will the dns also be decomissioned when decomission DC Server?
2. if 1 is false, can the dns be preserved and still be AD integrated zone? or should i update the dns settings manually to the new server?
3. if 1 is true, is it ok to build a secondary name server with master server poineted to the new AD's dns service?

Comment: Where are the zones stored? If they are stored in AD, you need to export them to files, remove AD, and then reinstall/reconfig DNS to read the data from files instead of AD.

Comment: I was confused by this too @Craig620 but I *think* the OP isn't actually talking about decommissioning AD but rather just an old DC. OP perhaps you can clarify your question - it currently reads like you want to decommission Your AD domain while keeping AD integrated DNS, which clearly makes no sense at all.

Comment: My requirement is only removing old DC server but keep the DNS on the old DC server with AD integrated zone, not the entire AD domain. I will refine my question, tks.

Answer (score 0):

1. is False: You can remove active directory roles without removing DNS, and it can continue to be an authorized DNS server in your AD Environment, (same as DHCP and other roles)

Also,
DNS is a dependency of AD,
AD is not a dependency of DNS.